# React: Slider with useEffect hook not working properly when trying to save the slider's state into local storage

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, slider, use-effect

I'm trying to save the state of my slider in local storage using the UseEffect hook, so the selected value in the slider doesn't get lost when the user refreshes the page. However, the slider is acting weirdly when I add this functionality.

Here is the code in the parent component:

```
function ParentComponent() {
  const [prefState, setPrefState] = React.useState(50);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("pref_state");
    if (data) {
      setPrefState(JSON.parse(data));
    }
  }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.localStorage.setItem("pref_state", JSON.stringify(prefState));
  });


  const handlePrefSliderChange = (event, new_value) => {
    setPrefState(new_value);
  };
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
       <Grid item xs={12} >
         <CustomizedPrefSlider
           PrefSliderValues={prefState}
           onPrefSliderChange={handlePrefSliderChange} 
         />
       </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default ParentComponent;
```

Here is the code for the child component:

```
const PrefSlider = withStyles({
  root: {
    color: '#52af77',
    height: 8,
    padding: '13px 0',
  },
  track: {
    height: 8,
  },
  rail: {
    color: '#d8d8d8',
    opacity: 1,
    height: 8,
  },

})(Slider);
export default function CustomizedPrefSlider({PrefSliderValues, onPrefSliderChange}) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={classes.title}>
      <Typography className={classes.titleFont}>
        How important is this feature to you? 
      </Typography>
      </div>
      <div className={classes.root}>
        <PrefSlider
          aria-labelledby="discrete-slider"
          value={PrefSliderValues}
          onChange={onPrefSliderChange}
          min={0}
          max={100}
          step={25}
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Is this the correct way of saving the state of the slider to avoid losing data when the user refreshes the page? Why am I missing some of the stylings that I added to my slider when I add this functionality?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Doing it this way looks like it should technically work, but seems very inefficient.

I'd suggest using a custom made hook, something like [useLocalStorage](https://usehooks.com/useLocalStorage/) or [@rehooks/local-storage](https://github.com/rehooks/local-storage)

`useLocalStorage` is nice because the code is small and easy to understand, and it would shrink your code down to this:

```
const [prefState, setPrefState] = useLocalStorage(50);
```

Comment: Thanks! If I use Redux or React's context hooks, would I still need this custom hook?